# Bootstrap 3 permanent navbar

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3

In bootstrap 2 I had navbar with icon out of collapse and stay so on mobile device in one line.
But with bootstrap 3, this navbar didn't stay in the same line, there are 1 line per link.

I tried different ways, like brand class or col-xs-2 (not gracefull), but no issue.

How to fix this navbar independently of the size of the device, without to change responsive website ?

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
<div class="container">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
      <li class="active"><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-home"></span></a></li>
      <li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span></a></li>
      <p class="navbar-text">Short TXT</p>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: See this http://getbootstrap.com/components/#navbar-default

Comment: I don't want to change collapsing point if you suggest that, because I need it like in default.

Comment: Are you looking for a fixed navbar in mobile layout?

Comment: Yes, for a part of a navbar. The other part is in collapse.

Comment: Are you saying you don't want `Short TXT` to collapse?

Comment: Icon and short text, but it is in major case for icon.